# What requirements must we meet when using Wikipedia content?

Tags: discussion

A recent [comment by mattdm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7962/how-does-the-human-eye-compare-to-modern-cameras-and-lenses/7970#7970) questioned the validity of a reply that quoted Wikipedia. So my question is: what are the key conditions we must observe, when re-using Wikipedia content, to satisfy their licensing conditions and terms of use?

Answer (score 6):

<strike>We can't include Wikipedia content beyond reasonable fair-use excerpts. Wikipedia content is CC-BY-SA 3.0, and unless one is the copyright owner of the specific copied text, one has no right to re-license it under the CC-BY-SA 2.5 license required by this site.</strike>

As of April 2011, sites on the Stack Exchange network are now using CC-BY-SA 3.0, which means that as long as [the normal attribution requirements](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/how-to-attribute-flickr-creative-commons-photos-online) are followed, Wikipedia and Stack Exchange content can be intermixed.

However, it's still questionable whether answers which *merely* copy and paste Wikipedia articles add any value to the site. Pointing someone to Wikipedia for more details, or using it as a basis for exposition is one thing, but just lifting the bulk of an article doesn't really benefit anyone.

Comment: I agree that merely copying content(from any source) in lieu of writing one's own answer is very questionable. The person concerned could, at a minimum, have summarised or interpreted the Wikipedia content. I am still trying to wrap my mind around the 2.5 vs 3.0 issue